# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, assigning equal names to diff variables?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, typeerror, xpress-optimizer

I've been at this problem for a few hours now, I seem to have named an integer variable and a function the same but I just don't know which variable/function I am assigning the same name to. Here's the function where the error occurs:

```
def Automatic(fee):
    excel_file = "stocklist.xlsx"
    data = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    #print(data)
    L = data["Unnamed: 0"].tolist()
    print("Stock list generated:", L)
    p = []
    print("Transaction fee: ",fee*100, "%")
    print('----------------------------------------')
    for i in range(len(L)):
        p.append(float(stock_info.get_live_price(L[i])))
        print("Current price of "+L[i]+": ",p[i])
    print('----------------------------------------')
    return [L,p]
```

The error that appears on the terminal is:

```
<ipython-input-35-df30698b28ab> in Automatic(fee)
    156     print("Transaction fee: ",fee*100, "%")
    157     print('----------------------------------------')
--> 158     for i in range(len(L)):
    159         p.append(float(stock_info.get_live_price(L[i])))
    160         print("Current price of "+L[i]+": ",p[i])

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Edit: when I do print(type(range)), it returns class so i guess that is the problem, does anyone know where this instance is attributed in the package xpress? I did not assign any int variable the name "range".

Comment: Either `len` or `range` has been set to an int.

Comment: It's impossible to be certain without seeing more of your code, but evidently either `len` or `range` is responsible - or both.

Comment: can it be related to the import of the xpress "package"? my code worked fine when I hadnt imported this.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining that importing a package would overwrite `len` or `range` in an invalid way. You really have to show all your code or at least a running example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I found the source of the error and it was indeed an import, namely:  " from xp import * " (i imported xpress as xp), this overwrote the function range() for an integer value range=4, god knows why, I should have indeed put my import codes. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `xpress` package defines constants like `leq`, `geq`, `eq`, and `range` to specify the type of constraints (<=, >=, ==, or ranged).
If you just import everything from the package then this will overwrite the builtin definition of `range` with an integer constant (in this case 4).

So it is better to limit the things you pull into your namespace by doing something like

```
from xpress import leq, geq, eq, problem
```

or whatever it is you need. Our just do

```
import xpress as xp
```

and qualify all the xpress-related things by prepending `xp.`. This has the advantage that it is immediately clear that you are calling xpress-related functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, the `xpress` module has a `range` keyword for adding range constraints to an optimization model. To avoid obscuring the built-in `range` keyword in Python, starting from version 8.13 of the Xpress Optimizer module the `xpress.range` keyword will be supplanted by `xpress.rng`.